# How can I remove this error when running hive command - `hbase not found in ....bin?`

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

Whenever I run "hive" command in terminal, it gives me a few errors before starting. I've seen some errors normally running on other people's PC but not this particular one where it says no hbase. queries don't run because of these errors

```
/usr/bin/which: no hbase in (/home/evirac/.local/bin:/home/evirac/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/home/evirac/hadoop/hadoop/sbin:/home/evirac/hadoop/hadoop/bin:/home/evirac/hadoop/hadoop/sbin:/home/evirac/hadoop/hadoop/bin:/home/evirac/hadoop/hive/bin)
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/evirac/hadoop/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/evirac/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Hive Session ID = 601ecfde-b638-4970-bd2d-0287e5414201

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/evirac/hadoop/hive/lib/hive-common-3.1.2.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
hive> SHOW DATABASES;
FAILED: HiveException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
hive>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive shouldn't have a direct dependency on Hbase, but you could install it, and add it's bin directory to your PATH - https://hbase.apache.org

However, your error is related to the Hive metastore, not Hbase. The work on the Hbase metastore was abandoned in Hive 3 - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseMetastoreDevelopmentGuide

As asked before - What happens when you use `beeline`, the preferred Hive client?

Comment: ```SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/evirac/hadoop/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/evirac/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Beeline version 3.1.2 by Apache Hive
beeline> SHOW DATABASES;
No current connection```

Comment: ^ when i use beeline

Comment: Yeah, that's expected output if you don't provide `-h` for a connection string such as `-h jdbc:hiveserver2://localhost:10000`. Make sure to use correct address

Comment: Meant `-u` not `-h`. Details here - https://sparkbyexamples.com/apache-hive/connect-to-hive-using-beeline/